# Getting results from a stored procedure to populate a GridView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a windows aspx form that I have a `TextBox`, `Button` and a `GridView`. The `TextBox` is stored as a variable @subschedule and passed to a stored procedure. What I'd like to do is to populate the results of that procedure into my `GridView`. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to `System.Data.SqlClient`

Then create a method for your calling your stored procedure... Maybe wrap it up in a class for database calls.

```
public static class DataBase
{
    public static DataTable myProcedureName(String subSchedule)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();

        using (var cnx = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand {
            Connection = cnx,
            CommandText = "myProcedureName", 
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Parameters = {
                new SqlParameter("@subSchedule", subSchedule)
            }
        })
        {
            try
            {
                cnx.Open();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                return dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error executing MyProcedureName.", ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it...

```
gvMyGrid.DataSource = DataBase.myProcedureName(txtSubSchedule.Text);
gvMyGrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two popular options:

1.. Code Behind:

```
string subSchedule = txtSubSchedule.Text.Trim();

//you'll create a new class with a method to get a list of customers
//from your database as others answers have demonstrated
IEnumerable<Customer> custs = MyDataLayer.GetCustomers(subSchedule);

myGrid.DataSource = custs;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

2.. Use a SqlDataSource. This is a quick and dirty way to bind your ASP.NET server control to a stored procedure. It's got its easy implementation pros, and some other cons :

```
 <asp:GridView  id="myGrid"
            runat="server"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true"
            DataSourceID="ds1" />

        <asp:SqlDataSource
            id="ds1"
            runat="server"
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyNorthwind%>"
            SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"                
            SelectCommand="GetSchedule">
              <SelectParameters>
                  <asp:ControlParameter name="SubSchedule" 
                          ControlID="txtSubSchedule" Propertyname="Text"/>
              </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `DataSource` property:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

// Open the connection 
using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection( 
       "Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AcmeRentals;Integrated Security=True")) 
{ 
    cnn.Open();

    // Define the command 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand()) 
    { 
        cmd.Connection = cnn; 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
        cmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

        // Define the data adapter and fill the dataset 
        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd)) 
        { 
            da.Fill(dt); 
        } 
    } 
} 

// This is the key code; you can set the DataSource to "collection"
gridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
gridView.DataBind();
```

Source: http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/07/dal-retrieve-a-datatable-using-a-stored-procedure.aspx

Comment: Nate, I modified my code as you suggested and see Rows = {System.Data.DataRowCollection} being 1, but I don't see any data in my GridView. I can post the code if you need to see how it's currently structured.

Comment: You may need to use the `.DefaultView` property of the data table.

Comment: Nate, where would the .defaultview come into my code? Would it be part of the key code? or part of filling the dataset?

Comment: Check my edit, basically `gridView.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 0):

```
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "SPPUBLISHER";
    adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    connection.Close();
    GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Full Source..[gridview from procedure](http://asp.net-informations.com/gridview/procedure.htm)